# Type annotations for abstract classes that are coupled by a shared, arbitrary type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

*(I'm rather new to Python's type annotations and mypy, so I'm describing my problem in detail in order to avoid running into an XY problem)*

I have two abstract classes that exchange values of an arbitrary but fixed type:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')  # result type


class Command(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self, runner: Runner[T]) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Runner(ABC, Generic[T]):
    def run(self, command: Command[T]) -> T:
        return command.execute(self)
```

In my implementation of this interface, the `Command` subclass needs to access an attribute of my `Runner` subclass (imagine that the command can adapt to runners with different capabilities):

```py
class MyCommand(Command[bool]):
    def execute(self, runner: Runner[bool]) -> bool:
        # Pseudo code to illustrate dependency on runner's attributes
        return runner.magic_level > 10


class MyRunner(Runner[bool]):
    magic_level: int = 20
```

This works as expected, but doesn't satisfy mypy:

```
mypy_sandbox.py:24: error: "Runner[bool]" has no attribute "magic_level"  [attr-defined]
```

Obviously, mypy is correct: the `magic_level` attribute is defined in `MyRunner`, but not in `Runner` (which is the type of the argument to `execute`). So the interface is too generic -- a command doesn't need to work with any runner, only with some runners. So let's make `Command` generic on a second type var, to capture the supported runner class:

```py
R = TypeVar('R')  # runner type
T = TypeVar('T')  # result type


class Command(ABC, Generic[T, R]):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self, runner: R) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Runner(ABC, Generic[T]):
    def run(self, command: Command[T, Runner[T]]) -> T:
        return command.execute(self)


class MyCommand(Command[bool, MyRunner]):
    def execute(self, runner: MyRunner) -> bool:
        # Pseudo code to illustrate dependency on runner's attributes
        return runner.magic_level > 10


# MyRunner defined as before
```

This satisfies mypy, but when I try to use the code, mypy complains again:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    command = MyCommand()
    runner = MyRunner()
    print(runner.run(command))
```

```
mypy_sandbox.py:35: error: Argument 1 to "run" of "Runner" has incompatible type "MyCommand"; expected "Command[bool, Runner[bool]]"  [arg-type]
```

This time I don't even understand the error: `MyCommand` is a subclass of `Command[bool, MyRunner]`, and `MyRunner` is a subclass of `Runner[bool]`, so why is `MyCommand` incompatible with `Command[bool, Runner[bool]]`?

And if mypy was satisfied I could probably implement a `Command` subclass with a `Runner` subclass that uses "a different value" for `T` (since `R` is not tied to `T`) without mypy complaining. I tried `R = TypeVar('R', bound='Runner[T]')`, but that throws yet another error:

```
error: Type variable "mypy_sandbox.T" is unbound  [valid-type]
```

**How can I type-annotate this so that extensions as described above are possible but still type-checked correctly?**

Comment: In something like Java, you'd use `class Command<T, R extends Runner<T>>`, but I don't think Python's type annotations support type variables with generic bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current annotations are indeed a contradiction:

- The `Runner` allows only `Command`s of the form `Command[T, Runner[T]]`.
- The `execute` method of `Command[bool, Runner[bool]]` accepts *any* `Runner[bool]`.
- The `execute` method of `MyCommand` only accepts any "`Runner[bool]` *with a `magic_level`*".

Therefore, `MyCommand` is not a `Command[bool, Runner[bool]]` – it does not accept any "`Runner[bool]` *without a `magic_level`*". This forces MyPy to reject the substitution, even though the reason for it happens earlier.

---

This issue can be solved by parameterising over `R` as the self-type of `Runner`. This avoids forcing `Runner` to parameterise `Command` by the *baseclass* `Runner[T]`, and instead parameterises it by the actual *subtype* of `Runner[T]`.

```py
R = TypeVar('R', bound='Runner[Any]')
T = TypeVar('T')  # result type

class Command(ABC, Generic[T, R]):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self, runner: R) -> T:
        raise NotImplementedError()


# Runner is not generic in R
class Runner(ABC, Generic[T]):
    # Runner.run is generic in its owner
    def run(self: R, command: Command[T, R]) -> T:
        return command.execute(self)
```

Comment: But then you can write things like `Command[int, str]`, where the second type parameter isn't a runner at all.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Indeed, I missed that my definition of ``R`` is different from the one used in the question. See the recent edit.

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, your example doesn't type check for me in its current state: mypy (0.790) says ` Missing type parameters for generic type "Runner"` in the definition of `R`.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker I am also using MyPy 0.790. Can you compare against the [complete code](https://gist.github.com/maxfischer2781/67846712d566d0d0a4ff307a3fc53371)?

Comment: The error goes away if I set [`disallow_any_generics`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-disallow_any_generics) to `False` (the default). But even if we ignore that problem then your code still allows me to create use `class MyBrokenCommand(Command[float, MyRunner])` without the type checker complaining -- because `R` is not bound to `T`.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker Yes, so does the initial specification. If a command knows how to get a ``T`` without using its ``Runner``, that is fine. ``MyRunner`` will refuse to ``run`` it, however, since it requires a ``Command[bool, ...]``.

Comment: That is true, and probably good enough. I'd still like to get this to run with `disallow_any_generics` enabled. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @FlorianBrucker Apparently, [MyPy expects ``R = TypeVar('R', bound='Runner[Any]')``](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7077#issuecomment-509009594).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the instance variable to the `Runner` interface:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


class Command(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self, runner: Runner[T]) -> T:
        pass


class Runner(ABC, Generic[T]):
    magic_level: int   # <- note the change to your code here!

    def run(self, command: Command[T]) -> T:
        return command.execute(self)
```

then your first implementation will run without errors. I feel that you also had an interface in mind that included the instance variable. Of course, the whole thing also works if `magic_level` is a `TypeVar` too or if it is characterized by a more open [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol).

Comment: My issue is that `magic_level` is *not* supposed to be part of `Runner`, just of `MyRunner`. So your suggestion does not really fix the issue.